# Fuse bindings for php

Tags: php, fuse

I am writing an application that thus far has been written in PHP, from the interface to the daemons. I have a need to use [fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) and would like to continue to use PHP just for consistency. However, there doesn't seem to be bindings for PHP. Python, Java etc have bindings, and I can code in those languages I just dont want the additional dependencies in this project. I have seen a project on google code, but nothing complete. Anyone know if these have been written?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote an extension for PHP that provides bindings to libfuse. I have read support working, but haven't quite finished write support. Eventually I'll finish it, but if you'd like to futz with it, I'd be happy to take patches.

http://pecl.php.net/fuse

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at those other bindings, and write a PHP extension! :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is another binding available: https://github.com/fujimoto/php-fuse

This blog post explains how to install it: http://blog.728.lu/?p=5