# php editor source question

Tags: php, editor

Is there a php editor on the market witch can read sources straight from a mysql database?

Comment: Doubt it. Why do you have PHP source stored in a MySQL database?

Comment: Please use http://programmers.stackexchange.com for questions like this.

Comment: @marcog I'm not sure this belongs on programmers.SE. It's a technical question.

Comment: Clearly, Craige, because Grumpy likes having his server turned into a zombie on a server botnet.

Comment: @Pekka Perhaps, you're probably right.

Comment: @DampeS8N What kind of remark is that??? Very not done. I have several legit reasons for it. When your site reads css \ html from a database, why not the php source??

Comment: @marcog  i will ask it there to, not really sure where to post it

Comment: @Grumpy: Because if your database has any SQL injection points, I can add exec() commands to your source that would pwn your server. Then I could remove them leaving no trace that I was there. I could pwn your box without you knowing and with you having no way at all to know.

Comment: @Grumpy it's a legitimate question but I really doubt whether something like this exists. It looks like a bit of an outlandish requirement @Dampe I agree that storing code in a database is sub-optimal practice, but it is *not* a security hole in itself. "zombie botnet" comments are really unnecessary

Comment: Well, you could use one of the existing php online editors, and hack the [Horde VFS](http://pear.php.net/package/VFS/redirected) backend in, allowing you to read local files or a database file storage. Another alternative was writing your own [FUSE driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144707/fuse-bindings-for-php). Most sensible however would be to make your database contents available over WebDAV, allowing you to use Eclipse or so.

Comment: most ides are able to do FTP, so you could write a small ftp server in ruby or python or something and then internally wire it up to your mysql database.

Comment: thanks @mario, i added it as a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No....and maybe.

There is no reason why anyone should write a MySQL based editor.
Your best chance to archive this is to find a greedy and/or lunatic programmer that will write you a MySQL-virtual drive.
Yes this IS possible, and at least on windows it does not take much skills.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use one of the existing php online editors, and hack the Horde VFS backend in, allowing you to read local files or a database file storage. Another alternative was writing your own FUSE driver. Most sensible however would be to make your database contents available over WebDAV, allowing you to use Eclipse or so